# Django JsonResponse with safe=False to D3

Tags: json, django, d3.js

Developing a project with Django which involves serving JSON data to templates for use in javascript using the D3 framework.

A pattern I am using quite a bit is to return a JsonResponse object from a Django view with an *array* of data.  As I start to link up apps in the project, I am also starting to use this idea to pass data between views in different apps. To get this working, I also need to set a safe flag as False. e.g.

```
def my_view(request):

    data = [{'foo':'bar'}, {'but':'should'}, {'i':'care?'}]

    return JsonResponse(data, safe=False)
```

This works fine and I think I want to be passing arrays because it makes life easier in D3.  But it perturbs me a bit to be using this flag. I am somewhat reassured by the description in the Django documentation, but cannot say I have much understanding of the risk.

[django docs - jsonresponse](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/request-response/#jsonresponse-objects)

Any thoughts on how much of a security issue this potentially is, and what might be the best alternative approach if they are significant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you rightly point out, sending non-dict JSON objects was a concern for EMCAScript 3 and earlier according to the [Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/request-response/#jsonresponse-objects). (For those interested, here are the details of [how the attack was executed](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/159609/how-is-it-possible-to-poison-javascript-array-constructor-and-how-does-ecmascrip).)

However, EMCAScript 5 was [released in 2009 and was fully supported in major browsers by 2013](https://www.w3schools.com/Js/js_versions.asp). The release of EMCAScript 5 and subsequent browser adoption fixed this vulnerability, and it is now safe to send non-dict options. So, `safe=False` should only be relevant if you plan to support browsers released before 2013.

If your website restricts browser support (for example) by only offering TLS version 1.2 and 1.3 - [any browser that supports TLS 1.2](https://oktasupport.cadence.com/TLS1.2_BrowserSupport.html) and later will not be vulnerable to the JSON issue with EMCAScript, because those browser version came after EMCAScript 5 was fully implemented in major browsers.

In summary, there is little to no concern to setting this `safe` flag to `False` in the JSONResponse class. This is because the only possible way the vulnerability could be exploited is through ancient browsers.

Comment: Some water under the bridge since asking the question!  But still much appreciated Dylan - thanks